# Meteor 0.5.9 - Deps.Autorun fadein not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, meteor

I have the following code:

```
Template.jobFlash.helpers({
    latest_job: function(){
        if(Session.get("latestJob")!=""){

            return JobsCollection.findOne({}, {sort: {'added_date': -1}});
        }
    }
});
Deps.autorun(function(){

    var job = JobsCollection.findOne({}, {sort: {'added_date': -1}});
    sortArr = [];
    sortArr['_id'] = "asc";
    var oldJob = Session.get("latestJob");

    if(job && oldJob !== job._id){
        Session.set("latestJob", job._id);
            $("#jobHolder").fadeIn(750).delay(10000).fadeOut(750);
    }
});
```

And then:

```
<template name="main">
    {{#isolate}}
        {{> otherStuff}}
    {{/isolate}}
    {{#isolate}}
        {{> jobHolder}}
    {{/isolate}}
</template>


<template name="jobHolder">
    <div id="jobHolder" style="width:100%; position:absolute; top:0; left:0; height:100%; background:#FFF; display:none;">
    {{#with latest_job}}
    {{#isolate}}
    <div>
        <h1>{{job_title}} - ({{job_type}})</h1>
        <h2>{{job_company}}<br/>
            &pound;{{job_pay}}<br/>
            {{job_short_location}}</h2>
        <div id="map-holder"></div>
    </div>
    {{/isolate}}
    {{/with}}
    </div>
</template>
```

When JobCollection is updated with a new row, the fadeIn should be called - and it is when the page is first loaded and the autorun is triggered, the whole code block works fine. However, after that, if the JobsCollection is updated, the function is called and I can see the javascript executing, however the fadeIn just simply doesn't work. Why is this? It's almost as if the Autorun is losing scope?

Comment: Is that the exact jobHolder template? Or does the real one depends on some reactive vals as well?

Comment: @Xyand it does have some reactive vals, that's a very good point - if i take out said reactive vals, it works fine. is it because the reactive vals are causing the parent `div` to be reinserted? Shall I wrap the reactive vals in another `div` in an `{{#isolate}}`?

Comment: @Xyand I have updated the question to show my code - what I suggested didn't work. If I call `$("#jobHolder").fadeIn(750).delay(10000).fadeOut(750);` straight after, but outside of the autorun (inside console), the fadein works fine.

Comment: I have also tried placing the function call inside `Template.jobFlash.rendered` to no avail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had similar issues. Try the following:

1. `Template.jobHolder.preserve(["#jobHolder"]);`
2. Run the animation code in `Meteor.defer`